# Foreach error checkbox php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

First page form

```
<form action="calculatepage.php" method="post">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dvd_title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?>" name="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>

  <?php
        }
    ?>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

Second page

```
<?php

echo $_POST['checkbox']; //This shows up if the last checkbox is checked

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value) {
    echo print_r($value);
}
 ?>
```

It returns error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\calculatepage.php on line 15" at the second page.

How to fix this and show multiple checkbox values input from the first page?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `name="checkbox"` to `name="checkbox[]"` in the input.

Comment: when replacing `name="checkbox"` to `name="checkbox[]"` beware that  `echo $_POST['checkbox'];` will give error as now` $_POST['checkbox']` is array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line with the following
Check here `name="checkbox[]"`

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?>" name="checkbox[]"></td>
```

And `echo print_r($value);` is wrong. You should use `print_r();` or `var_dump();` for an array

Comment: when replacing `name="checkbox"` to `name="checkbox[]"` beware that  `echo $_POST['checkbox'];` will give error as now `$_POST['checkbox']` is array

Answer (score 0):

A form will only post checkboxes when they are checked. So if the user doesn't check anything, it will not post anything. You can fix that quite easily by inserting an empty array if nothing is posted.

AND you need to change the name to `checkbox[]`, otherwise it'll just post a string (or nothing).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" ... />

$checkboxes = is_array($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : array();
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
    // ...
}
```